# IQueryable Where integer property expression usage?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, iqueryable

So I have a query I'm constructing using Entity Framework, LINQ. Depending on the search parameter, and the type of the parameter being searched.

I have created a function like this:

```
public static IQueryable<T> WhereInt<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, string propertyName, string contains)
        {
            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "type");
            var propertyExpression = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyName);

            MethodInfo method = typeof(string).GetMethod("First");
            var someValue = Expression.Constant(contains, typeof(string));
            var containsExpression = Expression.Call(propertyExpression, method, someValue);

            return query.Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(containsExpression, parameter));

        }
```

Used as such:

```
WhereInt(DCs, searchfield, search);
```

`searchfield` could be userid, username, integer or string, and ideally I want to do:

```
searchfield.value == search.toInt32()
```

sort of feature.

I want to also make `DateTime` types searchable too. Maybe I'll make a `WhereDateTime` for that.

I get an error on `var containsExpression = Expression.Call(propertyExpression, method, someValue);`

This works fine with strings, but fails with the error:

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: method
```

Comment: string does not have a method named `First` which is why GetMethod("Firts") returns null. What are you trying to do. COuld you provide sample input and expected result

Comment: @RuneFS What I am trying to do is have a function like this:   query.Where(SearchField, SearchType, SearchValue); So I made two functions, one WhereInt and one WhereString, and I enter SearchField and SearchValue, and I'm trying to get it to return the correct value (using equal operation "==" for int, or .Contains() for string)

Comment: Maybe I mistakenly used "First", I was using "Contains" for that in WhereString... And I changed Contains to "First", hoping that will be the same as using == like in LINQ.

Comment: this expression still puzzles me `typeof(string).GetMethod("First")` you are saying you wish to compare ints but are looking for a method on string and what did you expect 1.First(someVariable) to return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `.First()` method on an integer value. I really don't know why you thought that would help you to generate an expression like `searchfield.value == search.toInt32()` (which doesn't say `First` anywhere). Use an Equal expression instead.

I think you're looking for something more along these lines.

```
public static IQueryable<T> WhereInt<T>(IQueryable<T> query, string propertyName, string value)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "type");
    var propertyExpression = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyName);

    var someValue = Expression.Constant(int.Parse(value), typeof(int));
    var containsExpression = Expression.Equal(propertyExpression, someValue);

    return query.Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(containsExpression, parameter));
}
```

Comment: I was just experimenting with something similar. Except my mistake was I had "Equals" where you have "Equal" and "propertyexpression, containsexpression" as arguments for lambda instead of "con, parameter" like yours hehe. Anyway, testing it out.

Comment: So I get this error "The binary operator Equal is not defined for the types 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]' and 'System.Int32'."

Comment: I'm guessing because it is a type of 'int' that "allows nulls", it recognizes it as int? and using .Constant() makes that fail.

Comment: @Dexter: Yes, that's right. You can either modify the method to treat the input as a nullable int, or use `Expression.Convert(Expression, Type)` to mimic a cast from `int` to `int?`.